# UWP Frame PageNavigation

Tags: c#, navigation, controls, uwp, frame

I have a Problem with the Navigation System in UWP.

I have 3 different pages which contains the BackRequested Event.
The Problem is that the Frame can not go back to the 2nd page.

for example:

```
Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> BACKBUTTON -> Page 1
```

I want to Access page 2 instead of the first page.

As I wanted to have a Navigation bar, I decided to create a Master page which contains a Frame Control inside. This Control is called for example "Layer".

I can navigate to the 2nd page with this Code

```
Layer.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2), this);
```

"this" contains the whole FirstPage which I Need to Access to the Layer from the second page.

When I want to call the 3rd page, the Code would be like this

```
_FirstPage.Layer.Navigate(BlankPage2),this);
```

I can get the FirstPage instance by using

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {FirstPage _FirstPage = e.Parameter as FirstPage;}
```

I think the Problem is that my FirstPage instance is different than the given Parameter in the 2nd page.

I can try calling the FirstPage (like

```
WinForm -> (Form1) master = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];)
```

but I don´t know how to get the open page...

What is the Standard for this?

How can I have a navigationbar with different pages in one page ??

I am sorry for the grammar. As Windows 10 Supports the Keyboard Input, It tries to correct any wor`enter code here`d from English to German.

*edit

I´ve tried to create a test Project to see how it is working without UIElement (Frame)
I was able to get the correct BackStack. But unfortunately, the Problem is not solved!

```
   protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in this.Frame.BackStack)
            {

                count++;
                sb.AppendLine(item.SourcePageType.FullName + " " + count.ToString());


            }
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(sb.ToString());
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch
        {

        }


        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        currentView.BackRequested += CurrentView_BackRequested;



    }

    private void CurrentView_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Frame.CanGoBack == true) { this.Frame.GoBack();}
    }
    public BlankPage3()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

---

THIS IS MY MAIN CODE

```
  Sites.ContentPage cp = new Sites.ContentPage();
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Classes.Transmission.Passwort.CreateTransmissionPasswort ctp = e.Parameter as Classes.Transmission.Passwort.CreateTransmissionPasswort;
        this.PW = ctp.PW;
        this.cp = ctp.CP;

        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in cp.Layer.BackStack)
            {

                count++;
                sb.AppendLine(item.SourcePageType.FullName + " " + count.ToString());


            }
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(sb.ToString());
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch
        {

        }







        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        currentView.BackRequested += CurrentView_BackRequested1;
        if(Classes.CheckScreenState.GetFactorType() == Classes.CheckScreenState.DeviceForFactorType.Phone)
        {
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        if (Classes.CheckScreenState.GetFactorType() != Classes.CheckScreenState.DeviceForFactorType.Phone)
        {
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
        }

        }

    private void CoreWindow_PointerPressed(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.CurrentPoint.Properties.IsXButton1Pressed)
        {
            if (cp.Layer.CanGoBack == true) { cp.Layer.GoBack(); }
            var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
            currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;

        }
        if (args.CurrentPoint.Properties.IsXButton2Pressed)
        {
            if (cp.Layer.CanGoForward == true) { cp.Layer.GoForward(); }
            var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
            currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;

        }
    }

    private void CurrentView_BackRequested1(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cp.Layer.CanGoBack == true) {cp.Layer.GoBack(); e.Handled = true; }
        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;

    }
    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (cp.Layer.CanGoBack == true) {cp.Layer.GoBack(); e.Handled = true; }
        var currentView = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
        currentView.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

CP = ContentPage (MainPage)

Comment: Cant you use 

Window.Current.Frame as Frame and then find the name of frame. Then use that name to decide where to navigate?

Like if the name of current Frame is "BlankPage2" then it should go Navigate to "BlankPage1".
As the number of frames are limited you can manually override the Navigation

Comment: I´ve already tried. No chance. The problem seems to be in the backstack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a simple app which shows you navigation.

[image: Screen Capture]

The MainPage of the app is (lets call this rootpage) : FramePage.xaml
There are other 3 xaml pages (lets call them subpages) : Frame1.xaml, Frame2.xaml, Frame3.xaml

So, I have an frame in my rootpage and a Command Bar at the bottom with 2 buttons 'back' and 'next' to navigate through frames.

So when we click 'next' button it will go like this

> Frame1 -> Frame2 -> Frame3

When you click 'back' button, it will check if Frame can go back.
If it can, it will go back to previous frame.

To keep track of Frame I have kept a TextBlock in each frame which shows the Frame Name.

Here are the Codes.

For FramePage.xaml

**XAML**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Back" Label="back" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="back_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Forward" Label="forward" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="next_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Frame x:Name="mainFrame">

    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
public FramePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Frame1));
    }

    private void back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mainFrame.CanGoBack)
            mainFrame.GoBack();
    }

    private void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Type current = mainFrame.SourcePageType;

        if (current.Name == "Frame1")
            mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Frame2));

        if (current.Name == "Frame2")
            mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(Frame3));
    }
```

**Frame1.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 1" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

**Frame2.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 2" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

**Frame3.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="Frame 3" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps.